# Edit canonical question to ask about new related feature?

Tags: discussion, canonical

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081640/3058609) asks and answers "What do the `u` and `r` prefixes to strings mean in Python" and is a valuable and oft-used dupe target.

In a recent version of Python, an extra prefix was added: `f` which describes formatter strings, such that:

```
foo = "bar"
spam = f"eggs {foo}"  # -> "eggs bar"
```

Is it more appropriate to write and self-answer a new canonical question to "What is an f-string", or edit the linked question above to include the `f` prefix and edit the accepted answer to describe the new syntax?

Comment: I'd update existing one as syntax looks very similar and searching for "f" not going to do anything unlike "string prefix python"... (f-string is string of f-words, right? :) )